# Is this error message showing because of node version or because of my folder structure?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, node-modules

I get this error message when trying to run "nodemon, npm start, npm run dev". I've tried removing node_modules and adding them back but that doesn't work.

```
"[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

[terminal view of code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxag8.png)"

Comment: You might have to share the file structure, in order to understand the issue, I would suggest you to run the command in the directory where package.json is located.

Comment: Okay I will do so